# Undefined control sequence "\includegraphics"

Tags: graphics, errors, compiling

I recently got a weird error when I was trying to recompile an old document of mine. I am using the latest versions of MiKTeX and TeXstudio and I am using pdfLaTeX compiler. I made a minimum working example which also produces the error:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    test\\
    \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{image.jpg}
\end{document}
```

The .log file says the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.11 ...cludegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I tried reinstalling TeXstudio and MiKTeX, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update miktex in both user and admin mode, this is a duplicate

Comment: I updated MiKTeX in Admin Mode, thought that would've been enough. After updating in User Mode everything works fine. Thanks!